# How to get the latest "month year" string from a list of such strings?

Tags: python, string, list, date, max

How to get max month year string value from list values in python?

```
list = ['March 2020', 'January 2020', 'February 2021', 'May 2020', 'April 2019']
```

Output:

```
February 2021
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a `key` argument to `max`

```
import datetime
spam = ['March 2020', 'January 2020', 'February 2021', 'May 2020', 'April 2019']
print(max(spam, key=lambda dt: datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, '%B %Y'))
```

and as a side note - don't use `list` as name - it's a built-in function.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built-in [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module:

```
from datetime import datetime

dates = ['March 2020', 'January 2020', 'February 2021', 'May 2020', 'April 2019']
f = "%B %Y"
print(max([datetime.strptime(d, f) for d in dates]).strftime(f))
```

Explanation:

1. It is considered a bad practice to name variables to names that are already taken by built-in, so I renamed your `list` to `dates`.
2. I defined a variable, `f`, to store the format of each date, where `%B` means the full month name, and `%Y` means the full year.
   3.I use a list comprehension to iterate through the `dates` list, and convert each string into a `datetime.datetime` object using the [`datetime.datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) method, along with the `f` format defined earlier.
3. Finally, with the list of string converted to `datetime.datetime`object, we can use the built-in [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) method to find the latest date, and then convert the returned `datetime.datetime` object into the string with [`datetime.datetime.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime), using the `f` format.

Comment: can you please help on below issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66157574/how-to-get-unmatched-records-from-python-data-frame-1-only-but-not-from-data-fra

Answer (score 0):

For each position, split the string using the space `.split(" ")` and then use the `datatime` to compare. You can use an auxiliar var to save the index

Comment: This answer is very broad and unclear. Try to be more specific and actually show how to do those stuff you're suggesting

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

dates = ['March 2020', 'January 2020', 'February 2021', 'May 2020', 'April 2019']
datetime_list = [datetime.strptime(date, "%B %Y") for date in dates]
print(max(datetime_list).strftime("%B %Y"))
```