# how to get unmatched records from python Data frame 1 only but not from Data frame 2 in python

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date':['2013-11-24','2013-11-24','2013-11-24','2013-11-24', '2021-12-21'], 'Fruit':['Banana','Orange','Apple','Celery','hello'], 'Num':[22.1,8.6,7.6,10.2, 3.67], 'Color':['Yellow','Orange','Green','Green', 'red'], })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date':['2013-11-24','2013-11-24','2013-11-24','2013-11-24','2013-11-25','2013-11-25'], 'Fruit':['Banana','Orange','Apple','Celery','Apple','Orange'], 'Num':[22.1,8.6,7.6,10.2,22.1,8.6], 'Color':['Yellow','Orange','Green','Green','Red','Orange'], })
```

below code giving unmatched records from 2 Data frames but I want unmatched records from one Data frame only

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]) 
df = df.reset_index(drop = True) 
df_grpby = df.groupby(list(df.columns)) 
idx = [x[0] for x in df_grpby.groups.values() if len(x) == 1] 
df = df.reindex(idx) 
print(df)
```

Comment: Can anyone please help on this. i am getting below error when i am using below indexes =(df1!=df2).any(axis=1)
df3 = df2.loc[indexes]
print(df3)                                                                                                                            "Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects"
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects

Comment: Could you please help me on above one, i am trying since two days but i couldn't get. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Ann Zen can you please help me on above issue.

Comment: Did my answer help, or am I missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use [`pandas.DataFrame.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas-dataframe-apply) and [`pandas.DataFrame.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html#pandas-dataframe-isin):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2013-11-24', '2013-11-24', '2013-11-24','2013-11-24', '2021-12-21'],
                    'Fruit': ['Banana', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Celery', 'hello'],
                    'Num': [22.1, 8.6, 7.6, 10.2, 3.67],
                    'Color': ['Yellow', 'Orange', 'Green', 'Green', 'red']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2013-11-24', '2013-11-24', '2013-11-24','2013-11-24','2013-11-25','2013-11-25'],
                    'Fruit': ['Banana', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Celery', 'Apple', 'Orange'],
                    'Num': [22.1, 8.6, 7.6, 10.2, 22.1, 8.6],
                    'Color': ['Yellow', 'Orange', 'Green', 'Green', 'Red', 'Orange']})

print(df1[~df1.apply(tuple, 1).isin(df2.apply(tuple, 1))])
print(df2[~df2.apply(tuple, 1).isin(df1.apply(tuple, 1))])
```

Output:

```
         Date  Fruit   Num Color
4  2021-12-21  hello  3.67   red
         Date   Fruit   Num   Color
4  2013-11-25   Apple  22.1     Red
5  2013-11-25  Orange   8.6  Orange
```